# can't use facades in phpspec

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, phpspec

I'm using laravel with phpspec.
The problem I've encountered is that I can't use any facades in my tests.
for example using using `Auth::guest()->willReturn(false);` throws an exception `A facade root has not been set.`
I can use facades in my code surely and I've tested my imports. 
Edit:

namespace spec\App;

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Prophecy\Argument;

class RegistersUserSpec extends ObjectBehavior {

function it_is_initializable()
{
    $this->shouldHaveType('App\RegistersUser');
}

public function it_disallows_guests_from_creating_a_task($auth)
{
    Auth::guest()->willReturn(false);
    $this->createTask('...')->shouldReturn('redirect');
 }
}
```

Comment: Can we see some more code?

Comment: @haakym sure, added test. mention if more is needed.

Comment: Have you tried `use Auth;` rather than use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`?

Comment: Or use `use Illuminate\Auth\Guard as Auth`

Comment: @haakym I don't think that's a problem related to Auth, I can't use other facades like ``User::create([...])``

Comment: Did you try `use Auth;` or not?

Comment: @haakym ``Class 'Illuminate\Auth\Guard' not found ``

Comment: Did you try simply `use Auth;`?

Comment: phpspec is a highly opinionated testing framework, it's been built to make it difficult to use practices considered bad.

Whenever you find it hard to test something, it's phpspec telling you that there's something wrong with your current design.

In your case, phpspec is suggesting you in a subtle way that Facades should be avoided, and dependency injection should be used instead.